# Dúvida referente Modal Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap-4

inseri um Modal em meu HTML, porém, por algum motivo aparentemente está preso em alguma parte do código , consigo visualizar o modal, mas não consigo realizar ações dentro dele , código e print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
          aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Cara caso tenha feito algo CSS também inclua na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente há outro elemento com o "z-index" maior que o seu na classe "modal". Tenta aumentar o tamanho do "z-index" da classe "modal" através do console e ver se resolve.

Comment: Era o Z-INDEX! Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

olhando por cima, a sua modal tem duas  a mais que o necessário (já me fez perder horas de trabalho, um  ou um a menos

esses modais devem ficar no final da pagina, logo antes do fechamento do , fora de qualquer outra tag